# How to set timeout inside if statement jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can't figure it out why this isn't working when I add `setTimeOut` to `if`,
am I doing something wrong, or how do I delay execution inside `if` statement?

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 1) {
    jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#page-top-anchor').offset().top }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() {
     jQuery('#'+$(this).data('modal')).fadeIn(1000); 
     jQuery('.a-modal').hide();       
    }, 1000);
```

This code is working completely fine without `setTimeout`, the problem in execution occurs only when I adding `setTimeout` to it.

Comment: `jQuery(‘.a-modal').hide();` should be `jQuery('.a-modal').hide();`. Check your syntax highlighting :P

Comment: If is also missing closing brackets.

Comment: this in above case is window. which element do you want to fadeIn? share your html code as well.

Comment: When do you call this if? Inside some scroll event handler? Can you provide full code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the complete callback of animate in this situation, by using setTimeout you'll eventually lose sync with the animate method due to performance issues.
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 1) {
jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#page-top-anchor').offset().top }, 1000 , function() {
 // when animation completes
 jQuery('#'+$(this).data('modal')).fadeIn(1000); 
 jQuery('.a-modal').hide();       
});
```

Comment: Your answer is looking 100% right but it is not working, animation stops and then nothin is happening, I'm using on click event by the way to trigger the function

Comment: It's probably related to '#'+ $(this).data as 'this' isn't the element, but the callback.
Please update your question with the HTML structure so I can update the answer.